# CSS - Why does this behave differently in Firefox/IE/Chrome?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I've got a pure CSS multi-layered drop-down menu (crazy, I know) and although it works perfectly in Firefox, when my friends checked the site using other browsers it kinda messed up:

- Internet Explorer adds a few pixels between drop-down menus, so you have to move the cursor really fast or it disappears
- Chrome makes them unusable by displaying submenus on top of each other

The website is [omartahir.com](http://omartahir.com) (yay, go me!) and the dropdown menus appear if you hover over 'Programming' and then one of the submenus, e.g. 'C++' - in IE there is a gap, and in Chrome the menu doesn't come out to the side but instead goes straight down!

Can anyone shed some light as to why this is happening? I'm not at all experienced with cross-browser compatibility or the differences between them :(

Here's the CSS (sorry there's so much!):

```
.navbutton
{
    color:#BBBBBB;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:45px;
    padding-top:17px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.navbutton2line
{
    height:55px;
    padding-top:7px;
}

.navbutton:hover, #navbuttonselected:hover
{
    color:#111111;
    transition-delay:0s;
}

#navbuttonselected
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#00A2E8;
}

/* CSS Dropdown Menu */

/* Programming */
#programming
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#programming > div
{
    display:none;
}

#programming:hover > div
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

/* /programming/cpp */
#cpp
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#cpp > div
{
    display:none;
}

#cpp:hover > div
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}

/* /programming/web */
#web
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#web > div
{
    display:none;
}

#web:hover > div
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}

/* /programming/python */
#python
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#python > div
{
    display:none;
}

#python:hover > div
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}

/* /programming/basic */
#basic
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#basic > div
{
    display:none;
}

#basic:hover > div
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
            <a href="/index.php" class="navbutton" id="navbuttonselected">Home</a
            ><a href="/about.htm" class="navbutton">About Me</a
            ><div id="programming"><a href="/programming.htm" class="navbutton">Programming</a>
                <div>
                    <div id="cpp"><a href="/programming/cpp.htm" class="navbutton">C++</a>
                        <div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/cpp/shooter.htm" class="navbutton navbutton2line">Shooter Game</a></div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/cpp/invoker.htm" class="navbutton navbutton2line">Invoker Practice</a></div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/cpp/gameoflife.htm" class="navbutton">Game of Life</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <div id="web"><a href="/programming/web.htm" class="navbutton navbutton2line">Web Development</a>
                        <div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/web/site.htm" class="navbutton">This Site</a></div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/web/coursework.htm" class="navbutton">Coursework</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <div id="python"><a href="/programming/python.htm" class="navbutton">Python</a>
                        <div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/python/p1.htm" class="navbutton">p1</a></div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/python/p2.htm" class="navbutton">p2</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <div id="basic"><a href="/programming/basic.htm" class="navbutton">SuperBASIC</a>
                        <div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/basic/b1.htm" class="navbutton">b1</a></div>
                            <div><a href="/programming/basic/b2.htm" class="navbutton">b2</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without browsing through your code, you may want to start with something like Normalize to make all browsers render elements the same. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Okay, I tried using it and it messed up some layout for Firefox and Chrome without solving the problem. Seems it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but nobody answered.

I have issues with my website. When I open the website, it behaves weird in Chrome. But Firefox and Safari are OK. I figured out the problem. So thought to share:

1. Use [this](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to create CSS without unnecessary things.
2. Try opening a website in incognito mode. If it is behaving ok, then you can follow two steps given below:

   Disable Extensions (in chrome - More tools --> extensions --> disable).
   Clear browser history (this helped me)
3. Open a website.

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)